# How to execute Laravel 5 Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and still getting my head around executing queries. I am stuck with this query that I can't figure out.

```
Models: Flag -> Quote -> QuoteItems

       1 - Quotes has many QuoteItems | QuoteItems has One Quote
       2 - Each Quote has one Flag(e.g accepted, rejected)


1- QuoteItems contains Profit and Price fields.
```

I need SUM(Profit) and SUM(Price) from all those quotes that are related to one flag.

Comment: Show us what you've tried already

Comment: Actually I have tried in cakePHP but I have no clue how to do that in Laravel. I can post cakephp query if you think that would help.

Comment: Do you have already those models? Have you described the relations between them?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following queries:

```
// Sum of price
$totalPrice= Quote->groupBy(' Flag')->sum('Price');

// Sum of profit
$totalProfit = Quote->groupBy('Flag')->sum('Profit');
```

For more information, head over to http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#aggregates